# No pdb file created in output directory for .dll in VS2012 MVC web app

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll, pdb-files

I am trying to debug a web app that I am running under IIS and localhost by attaching to the w3wp worker process.

I am getting the following message on my breakpoints when attached to the process:

**This breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols loaded for this document**

I have cleaned and re-built the solution numerous times so I am certain the cause of the problem is not that my code is out of sync with my app.

I have checked the modules view and can see that the symbols have been loaded for all the project dlls apart from the web project. The web.dll has a symbol status of

**No symbols loaded**

and when I check the output path I can see the web.dll but no web.pdb. All the other project dlls are present as are their corresponding pdb files.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the build configuration manager. Make sure they are all set to debug